# Creating a progressbar timeline for an online course

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, progress-bar

I'm creating an online course and I would like to create a horizontal progressbar-style timeline, that monitors the progress of the course and automatically displays the progress based on the current date.

Let's say for example that the course has the following events:

1. Course starts, 1.2.2015 17:30
2. Assignment number 1 deadline, 10.2.2015 23:59
3. Peer review deadline for assignment 1, 20.2.20.15 23:59
4. Assignment number 2 deadline, 1.3.2015 23:59
5. Course ends, 10.3.2015 23:59

What would be a smart way to approach this? I have googled around and found several javascript plugins related to timelines, but typically they seem to be for creating timelines of historic events. Is there something that is suitable for such a course progressbar?

Comment: You should provide some of your coding attempts.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Since you did not really descripted an programming related problem this question could be closed as off-topic. ([See here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). You should think about what you want to display. Progress over time. This can be easily done with percentages. Think about how much time passed from the total. Then you are able to display a progess-bar like elment and give it the size of x%.

Comment: [You could use `svg`.](http://dabblet.com/gist/c4872525878d5947477a) Now, all you need to do is calculate the total time in seconds and change the `dur` attribute in `animate` tag. A good thing about this approach is it doesn't require JavaScript.

Comment: Btw, if you want to increase the `width` of those lines simply increment all `h100`s and decrement `h-100`s. For example if you want to make those lines say 150px, all `h100` should be `h150` and all `h-100` should be `-150` in the `d` attribute of `path` tag.